# How to edit what is typed in command line?

Tags: shell

Typing a command like:

```
cat somefile
```

1. Press enter and run the command.
2. Then searching for it using ESC + k, allows me to bring it back.

I want to go back and edit the command while still typing in the prompt.
From what I understand, ESC + o would allow me to type over or go back what I wrote in the command.

However, those hotkeys do not seem to work, after the initial press. Though I am however able to edit after a few key presses of the arrow keys. Is there another way to edit command in the prompt that is retrieved using ESC + k?

Comment: What kind of shell are you talking about? (If you are unsure have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3327022/1870481))

Comment: Are you using Zshell? Sounds like you have `set vi` mode on.

Comment: ksh is the shell am I referring to.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the commandline-prompt, you are ready for inserting code:
You are in the vi edit mode.
You can look up a vi manual, here some commands for the commandline:

- ESC
  Leave the insert mode and enter the command mode.
- ESC /somecommand ENTER n n
  Look for somecommand. n n are looking for the next twice
- ESC wwb3w
  Go forward 2 words, back 1 word and forward 3 words
- ESC dwxx
  Delete word and two timews 1 character
- ESC lllcw
  3 positions to the left, change word
- ESC wrs
  Go forward 1 word and replace character by an s

Comment: What I am referring to is the command prompt in the shell, like ksh.

For example:

$ cat somefile

Comment: Yeah me too. The above examples all work on the command line. When you stand at the end of the line `$ cat omefile` and you see you forget an `s`, press `ESC bis ENTER` (Escape, 1 word back, insert, letter s and execute)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is.
You can use "!!" for previous command.
For Example:

```
$ cat file.txt
$ !! file2.txt # this will output both file.txt and file2.txt
```

Also you can pipe them to other commands.

```
$ !! | some_command  # it will pipe just previous command's output to some_commands
```

AND... If you want to execute 5th previous command

```
$ !-5
```

if you don't know the order of that command then,

```
$ history
233 cat file.txt
234 ls
235 date
$!234 # this will execute ls command
```